# How to implement multi user support using fos user bundle

Tags: doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I've been working on a multi users web application using symfony 3.4 framework with fos user bundle in order to easily manipulate users.
I've integrated the bundle and everything work fine except that the bundle features don't match my need when it comes to multi users through inheritance ! 
Is there any trick to implement the multi user inheritance in fos bundle ?

I've tried a lot of different tricks like changing the roles , changing the user model interface, using symfony groups but all of them seemed to be not working  ! 
The thing that will solve [with an ugly way] my problem is to change the value of the discriminator column  .

```
  * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="typeutilisateur", type="string")
  * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"Parent"="User","admin" = 

  "Administrateur","association"
    ="AsoociationsBundle\Entity\Association",
"Demandeurservice"="EldersStoryBundle\Entity\Demandeurservice",
     "Formateur"="FormationBundle\Entity\Formateur"
  ,"Prestataire"="AnnonceEldersCareBundle\Entity\Prestataireservice"})

 class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $prenom;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="adresse", type="string", length=50)
 */
private $adresse;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="integer")
 */
private $telephone;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sexe", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $sexe;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="datecreation", type="datetime")
 */
private $datecreation;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="avatar", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $avatar;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

}







/*This is the sub class*/



   <?php

 namespace EldersStoryBundle\Entity;

 use AppBundle\Entity\User;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
   * Demandeurservice
   *
   * @ORM\Table(name="demandeurservice")
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EldersStoryBundle\
   Repository\DemandeurserviceRepository")
   */
  class Demandeurservice extends User
  {


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="typemaladie", type="string", length=50)
 */
private $typemaladie;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="descriptionmaladie", type="string", length=255)
 */

private $descriptionmaladie;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="etatmaladie", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $etatmaladie;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pointelderly", type="integer")
 */
private $pointelderly;


 }
```

Everytime i subscribe i get the row in the table but with a discriminator column value ="parent"
So is there any major way to get this done ? or at least to change the value of the discriminator column ?

Comment: Thanks ! it worked for me
Cheers :')

Comment: Posted comments as an answer :-) (removed the comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `DiscriminatorMap`. If you don't create one, Doctrine will generate one automagically. So long as you don't go messing around with names of Entity objects (ie, change `Person` to `Persona`, or whatever) then that's your best bet. It's also more dynamic because if/when you add additional types, it will update it for you (when cache is removed).

[See here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance), last bullet point quoted:

> If no discriminator map is provided, then the map is generated automatically. The automatically generated discriminator map contains the lowercase short name of each class as key.